# List of visited links in CefSharp

Tags: c#, vba, winforms, chromium, cefsharp

Is there a way to get the list of visited links in the CefSharp framework? It stores them but how can we access them ?

Comment: There is no API for that.

Comment: I ended up adding entries in a txt file on the `TitleChanged` event. Awesome framework btw!

Comment: Think I misunderstood your question, search for GetNavigationEntries

Comment: Can you tell me an example of its implementation?

Comment: There isn't one currently. Follows the same pattern as the other visitor methods. Just read the interface XML doc, it's pretty simple.

Comment: I want to use other visitor methods too. But don't know how to. New to C#.

Comment: Look at the source for some examples.

Comment: `ICookieManager dCookieManager = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
 List<Cookie> cookies = await dCookieManager.VisitAllCookiesAsync();

 foreach (Cookie c in cookies)
 {
  if (c.HttpOnly)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(c.Domain);
  }
 }`

How I read cookies the other day. Something like this?